# Kotlin + Gradle Kotlin DSL + KAPT + MapStruct

Tags: kotlin, spring-boot, gradle, entity, dto

Всем доброе время суток.
Столкнулся с проблемой при попытке добавить функционал MapStruct в проект. Причем, ошибки появляются просто как снежный ком, одна за другой. Буду рад любой помощи.
По порядку:

1. Для начала, я не понимаю, почему Intellij IDEA не может корректно понять использование `kapt`. Собственно, все время выходит ошибка `Unresolverd reference: kapt`. В то же время IDE предлагает импортировать некий класс `import org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.Kapt.kapt`, в результате, конструкцию `kapt` можно использовать в блоке `dependencies`, однако в качестве аргумента ожидается экземпляр класса `KaptOptions`, который, похоже, мне совсем не нужен. Если же убрать импорт - IDE ругается на `unresolved reference: kapt`, однако build проекта проходит успешно. Не скажу, что это критично, но сильно врезается в глаза и отвлекает. И вообще не хотелось бы иметь никаких "красных" файлов, к тому же IDE постоянно предлагает сделать импорт "красного" `kapt`, что тоже неудобно.
2. В проекте имеется сущность System. При попытке выполнить `gradle clean build` выходит ошибка:
   `e: <path_to_class>\System.java:3: error: System is already defined in this compilation unit import java.lang.System;`
   Никакого импорта `java.lang.System` в классе сущности `System` (да и в принципе нигде более) не имеется.
   Если переименовать сущность, например в `Systemm` - ошибка исчезает, но не хотелось бы прибегать к такому методу.

```
package com.sprojects.core.server.model.entity

import java.util.Date
import javax.persistence.Column
import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.FetchType
import javax.persistence.Id
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne
import javax.persistence.OneToMany
import javax.persistence.PreUpdate
import javax.persistence.Table
import javax.persistence.Temporal
import javax.persistence.TemporalType

@Entity
@Table(name = "systems")
data class System(
    // ... Some fields here ... //
) {
   // ... Some code here //
}
```

3. Не создаются реализации мапперов MapStruct. Видимо, этот вопрос тесно связан с вопросом 2, но тем не менее никак не получается это решить. Пытаюсь получить маппер: `val mapper = Mappers.getMapper(MyConverter::class.java)`. Ошибка: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find implementation for com.sprojects.core.server.model.dto.impl.MyConverter`.
   Содержимое **build.gradle.kts***:

```
plugins {
    // kotlin
    id("kotlin")
    kotlin("jvm")
    kotlin("kapt")
    kotlin("plugin.spring")
    kotlin("plugin.jpa")
    // Spring
    id("org.springframework.boot")
    id("io.spring.dependency-management")
    // Other
    id("idea")
    id("com.palantir.docker")
    id("org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint")
    id("net.ltgt.apt") version "0.21"
    id("net.ltgt.apt-idea") version "0.21"
}

group = "${rootProject.group}"
version = "${rootProject.version}"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
java.targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom(configurations.annotationProcessor.get())
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    implementation("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:${rootProject.extra["jwtVersion"]}")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("org.springframework.security.oauth.boot:spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure:${rootProject.extra["springBootVersion"]}")
    implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-jwt:${rootProject.extra["springSecurityJwtVersion"]}")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")

    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:testcontainers:${rootProject.extra["testContainersVersion"]}")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:postgresql:${rootProject.extra["testContainersVersion"]}")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")

    implementation(
        group = "io.springfox",
        name = "springfox-swagger2",
        version = "${rootProject.extra["swagger2Version"]}"
    )
    implementation(
        group = "io.springfox",
        name = "springfox-swagger-ui",
        version = "${rootProject.extra["swagger2Version"]}"
    )
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    implementation(
        group = "org.mapstruct",
        name = "mapstruct",
        version = "${rootProject.extra["mapStructVersion"]}"
    )
    // При такой попытке не работает сборка проекта
    kapt("org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${rootProject.extra["mapStructVersion"]}")

    // При такой попытке работает сборка, но не создаются реализации мапперов
    /*annotationProcessor(
        group = "org.mapstruct",
        name = "mapstruct-processor",
        version = "${rootProject.extra["mapStructVersion"]}"
    )*/
}
```

Буду рад любой оказанной помощи, если нужно предоставить еще какие-то данные - предоставлю. Спасибо.

**UPDATED**. Вопрос 1 не актуален. Помогла подсказка IDE: `Apply Context`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как и было сказано, вопрос 3 полностью зависит от вопроса 2.

В результате совершил два действия:

1. Добавил файл **gradle.properties** в корень проекта:

   ```
   kapt.include.compile.classpath=false
   kapt.use.worker.api=true
   ```
2. Добавил дополнительную конфигурацию в **build.gradle.kts** :

   ```
   kapt {
       correctErrorTypes = true
   }
   ```

На всякий случай: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html

Answer (score 1):

> В проекте имеется сущность System. При попытке выполнить gradle clean build выходит ошибка: e: \System.java:3: error: System is already defined in this compilation unit import java.lang.System; Никакого импорта java.lang.System в классе сущности System (да и в принципе нигде более) не имеется. Если переименовать сущность, например в Systemm - ошибка исчезает, но не хотелось бы прибегать к такому методу.

Данный импорт добавляется при генерации кода и поэтому возникает конфликт. Предлагаю попробовать явно указать импорт java.lang.System определив для него другой псевдоним.

```
import java.lang.System as javaLangSystem
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Однако, я не понял, как я смогу таким образом повлиять на генерацию импорта, ведь при повторном выполнении команды `java.lang.System` вновь импортируется в обычном виде, без псевдонима. Однако решение нашлось, предоставлю его ниже.